# werkzeug DispatcherMiddleware with separate ports

Tags: flask, werkzeug

I'm playing with combining a couple flask apis that I have into one application that can be a little easier to deploy and set up for devs instead of needing three separate applications running. Currently each api resides on a separate port. I'm trying to use the DispatcherMiddleware to run all three applications but so far it seems like you can only use prefixes like

```
from frontend import app as frontend
from TestApi import app as test
from DevApi  import app as dev
from werkzeug.serving import run_simple
from werkzeug.wsgi import DispatcherMiddleware

app = DispatcherMiddleware(frontend, {
    '/test':     test,
    '/dev':      dev
})
run_simple('localhost', 4000, app, use_reloader=True)
```

now all my services run on 4000 but what id like to have is something like this

```
from frontend import app as frontend
from TestApi import app as test
from DevApi  import app as dev
from werkzeug.serving import run_simple
from werkzeug.wsgi import DispatcherMiddleware

app = DispatcherMiddleware(frontend, {
    ':5000':     test,
    ':6000':      dev
})
#frontend runs on 4000, test runs on 5000, dev runs on 6000
run_simple('localhost', 4000, app, use_reloader=True)
```

Am I just asking for something that makes no sense or is there a way to accomplish using this or another setup.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've come to the conclusion that this is a stupid idea that is very fragile and requires a lot of unnecessary complexity. I've instead just opted to write a bash script that starts all the apps as separate wsgi instances on their own port.

Answer (score -1):

The Flask documentation on application dispatching contains no hint on port based dispatching. As you mentioned you can simply start separate wsgi instances, as far as I know this is the only possible way using Werkzeug.

Reference: http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/latest/patterns/appdispatch/

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/13141363)

Comment: Thanks for the remark - never actually commented on stackoverflow before. Will surely consider this in the future, nonetheless I consider the link to be very helpful as it helped myself a lot searching an answer.